# Propagating result back to original activity from set of chained library activities

Tags: android, android-library

A bit of background, I'm currently developing a library which has some activities components and "entry points". The goal is, in its simplest description, for the library to take control of the UI, do some work based on series of UI interactions, and eventually propagate the result back to the original non-library activity. I've tried to summarise the flow in the following diagram:

[image]

As you can see, one can enter the library by starting activity B1 or B2, eventually reaching activity D.

**Q:** From a design point of view, what would be the best (or preferred) way of propagating the result back to A?

I've experimented with starting B1/B2 with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` for in-library activities until finally D is started with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` so it becomes the "top" and only activity in the task. However, this doesn't seem to work correctly and I also need it to be compatible with API Level 10.

Another issue is, activity A may be anything and is not known in advance and passing A.class about feels very ugly.

It seems perhaps this may be a problem that is best solved with the use of a service?

**Edit:**
To further simplify the concept of the problem, the main issue dealt with here is very much akin to a "callback" mechanism where the callback is delivered to the original activity. Of course, callbacks with "listener"-like interfaces will not work as the original activity is suspended and neither will broadcasts get delivered if it is not currently running.

Also, to clarify, *only the library* should be considered for the solution as Activity A may come from any third-party project making use of this library.

Comment: I usually try to avoid these kinds of complication and simply have the needed data write into a `SharedPreferences` or any format you preferred so any `Activity` that needs the data will grab their share from there.

Comment: The issue with `SharedPreferences` is that the state/result should not be persisted in between library invocations. And there is no guarantee that activity A (or any other activity to which the result should be propagated) will clear the stored preference value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Service`, consider the use of the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) Class. It allows you to store global variables which can be accessed from multiple Activities.

Comment: The `Application` class makes no sense in a library project as any such definitions in the manifest are effectively ignored. And it poses an unnecessary restriction to force third parties using the library to use a supplied `Application` sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

Call the new activity B of your application from library class.
Use your redirect url

```
String redirecturl = "com.example.ThankYouScreen";
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("data", "DONE");
    returnIntent.setClassName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), redirecturl);
    startActivity(returnIntent);
```